# How to make the top div reach the bottom div for every device

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fix the CSS of my code so that the top div always reaches the top of the orange line. The orange line is fixed at the bottom for each device

CSS of the div that contains the orange line:

```
.orangeDiv {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  //height: 25vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Css of the highlighted div:

```
.highlighted {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 170px;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 90px;
  //overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

EDIT: I can change the css to anything doesn't have to be absolute position

Answer (score 0):

why do you have to use absolute positioning for this?
I would rather use position:relative; and float to accomplish this.

Comment: Yes I'm open to any suggestions, but the orange line has to stick to the bottom of the page too

Answer (score 0):

If you assign orangeDiv's height and highlighted's bottom the same value you probably would get them touching at all times

Comment: If I set them both equal to 70px for example, then the orange line becomes higher than the bottom of the page...

Answer (score 0):

my solution would look something like this: (you might need to change height values accordingly)

```
.orangeDiv {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px; 
  height:5vh;
  width:100%;
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.highlighted {
  position:absolute;
  height:95vh; 
  width:80%; 
  left:0px; 
  top:0px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Comment: Hi I tried your way with the first height as 22 and second as 78. Its touching the orange line now, but the orange line has some text under it which is why it needed to be at the bottom of the page. Right now, for some devices it floats in the air (added picture in question) and some devices the words get cut off.

Comment: that's the reason why I asked if you have to use absolute/fixed positioning -> if the div has always to be on the bottom of device you have to use fixed. See my updated answer.

Comment: So the problem I'm facing with this is that because the height is fixed in my case 25vh and 75vh for each, in some cases the text gets cut off at the bottom while in some cases it doesn't

Comment: can you post full HTML and css including the text please

Comment: I unfortunately cannot, but if I set the height to 0px; then I can achieve my result of the text never getting cut off. however, even the then the highlighted div does not always reach the bar. Is there a way get it to reach there when height  = 0px?

Comment: what element would have the height:0px; ?